# Constructor not defined error when executing batch apex

Tags: apex, batch

Ive been working on this class to update a field on a related record with a field (zone) on the account record. When I try to test using "Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new UpdateMarketPlaceFieldBatchV2(),200);" I get an error message "Line: 1, Column: 39 Constructor not defined: [UpdatezoeFieldBatchV2].()" What am I missing that is causing the error?

```
global class UpdatezoneFieldBatchV2 implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{
global String qry;
global integer recordsProcessed = 0;

global UpdatezoneFieldBatchV2(String q, String e){
    qry=q;
}

global Database.qryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    qry = 'Select Id, zone__c From Vehicle__c where Account__c != null';
    return Database.getqryLocator(qry);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Vehicle__c> scope){
    List<Vehicle__c> veh = [Select Id, zone__c From Vehicle__c where Account__c != null];
    Map<Id, Account> accts = new Map<id, Account>([SELECT zone__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM Vehicle__c WHERE Id = :scope)]);
    for(Vehicle__c e : veh){
        Account a = accts.get(e.Account__c);
        e.zone__c = a.zone__c;
        recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed  + 1;
    }
    update veh;
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed');        
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is literally accurate. You cannot instantiate your batch class via

```
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new UpdateMarketPlaceFieldBatchV2(),200);
```

because your batch class does not have a no-argument constructor, which the error represents as `[UpdatezoeFieldBatchV2].()`. Your constructor takes two required arguments, although it doesn't do anything at all with one of them:

```
global UpdatezoneFieldBatchV2(String q, String e){
    qry=q;
}
```

You must provide both when you instantiate the class.

---

As a side note, unless you are building a managed package and wish to expose this class to outside callers, you should not declare this class or any of its members `global`.